# How to do the retries based on an http error code using Python Backoff Library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to implement the retry mechanism for certain exceptions and a specific `http` error code 408.

Here's how my current snippet looks like:

```
@backoff.on_exception(
    backoff.expo,
    (requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout, requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout),
    max_tries=MAX_TIMEOUT_RETRY_COUNT)
def get_response_http_post(data, params, headers, url) -> dict:
    """ Returns the response as json for a http post request """
    response_dict = {}
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, data=data, params=params, headers=headers, timeout=REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
        response.raise_for_status()
        if response.text:
            response_dict = json.loads(response.text)
        if response.status_code:
            response_dict['status_code'] = response.status_code
        if response.reason:
            response_dict['reason'] = response.reason
        return response_dict
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout as err:
        logger.exception(f'ReadTimeout: {err}')
        raise requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout as err:
        logger.exception(f'ConnectTimeout: {err}')
        raise requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as err:
        logger.exception(f'ConnectionError: {err}')
        raise requests.exceptions.ConnectionError
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        logger.exception(f'Exception occurred while sending http request: {err}')
        raise requests.exceptions.RequestException
```

So as you can see I'm retrying the request for 2 types of exceptions and also I need to like do the same for the http code 408.

How can I achieve it using the same `backoff` library? Or is there any other way?

I've noticed that the library has something called `@backoff.on_predicate` decorator but not sure how can I use it for this usecase. Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `giveup` parameter (keyword argument):

```
def fatal_code(e):
    return 400 <= e.response.status_code < 500

@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo,
                      requests.exceptions.RequestException,
                      max_time=300,
                      giveup=fatal_code)
def get_url(url):
    return requests.get(url)
```

https://github.com/litl/backoff

Comment: It might be more helpful to avoid speculative answers. I believe `giveup` is also a _keyword argument_ (`kwarg`), not a _keyword_. Best to not confuse the two.